# JSONAPI call to return set of objects including self relations

Tags: get, json-api

I’m trying to make a JSONAPI GET request to return a specific set of `Foo`s.

```
url.com/foos?filter[foo.id]=13,14
```

This works – to an extent: `Foo` has a relation called `children` which includes all of the other `Foo`s  for which the `Foo` in question is `parent`, but the response of the GET request above includes an empty list of `children`. Something like:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "foos",
            "id": "13",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "myFoo",
            },
            "relationships": {
                "children": {
                    "data": []
                },
                "parent": {
                    "data": null
                }
            }
        }, 
        {...}
    ]
}
```

The only times the `children` list is populated is if a child `id` is also included in the url’s filter list, or when I send a request to GET a `Foo` directly. For example,

```
url.com/foos/13
```

gets a response of:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "foos",
            "id": "13",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "myFoo",
            },
            "relationships": {
                "children": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "type": "foo",
                            "id": "18"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "foo",
                            "id": "19"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "parent": {
                    "data": null
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I get a set of `Foo`s filtered by `id` and make sure each `Foo` includes a list of its child `Foo`s?

Answer (score 0):

JSON:API specification is agnostic about filter strategy:

> Note: JSON:API is agnostic about the strategies supported by a server. The filter query parameter can be used as the basis for any number of filtering strategies.
>   https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-filtering

So this is up to your implementation. But it seems like your implementation has a critical bug. If I understand you right, your API returns an empty array as [*resource linkage*](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-linkage) for `children` relationship even if the resource has related records. This is a critical bug. The server may not include a relationship at all or it may only provide a [*related resource link*](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-related-resource-links) but it must not provide an empty array under `data` key if the resource has related records. An empty array as *resource linkage* data tells the client that there aren't any related records:

> Resource linkage MUST be represented as one of the following:
>
> - null for empty to-one relationships.
> - an empty array ([]) for empty to-many relationships.
> - a single resource identifier object for non-empty to-one relationships.
> - an array of resource identifier objects for non-empty to-many relationships.
>
> https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-linkage

As the issue is not related to JSON:API specification but to your concrete implementation and as the question does not include any server-side library your implementation is based on, it's impossible to tell the reason for this bug.